# Cytoscape.js curved lines with elkjs

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I have some graphs of 50-100 nodes. The edges are mostly tree-based but there are some cases where a child has multiple parents, and rarely some cycles. So it's directed cyclic graphs, mostly acyclic.

So far I haven't figured out a combination of elkjs settings that will give me curved lines that will avoid my nodes. I know these layouts are supposed to generate "bendpoints" but I'm not seeing them. I only have straight edges that intersect or go underneath intermediate nodes.

The stack is currently cytoscape.js, react-cytoscapejs, cytoscape.js-elk, and elkjs. On the cytoscape.js side, my edge styles have `'curve-style': 'bezier'` but it doesn't do anything - no curves at all. I've also arbitrarily tried `unbundled-bezier` but they just all swoop down like smiles:

[image]

That lower line is a good example, there are many cases where lines just seem to bisect other nodes; traveling right under the center points. Are there any examples of how cytoscape.js can use these directed layouts but with curved lines that properly avoid nodes? Some combination of elkjs layout options that I'm missing?

There are other issues I'm working through, like how to make each rank/layer a little better vertically aligned, and how to tell the layout algorithm the size of each node (which is discovered during the styling step as each node is a dynamically-sized svg background-image), but I'm most concerned about clean edges now.

Comment: Layouts settle the position of nodes, it's got nothing to do with edges. Did you check https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/359? Does the network look okay with less nodes (50)?